# Floating menu fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I want to create a floating menu that will stay on top when scrolling. I found some examples and was able to replicate them and it now works.
However, the problem is that as you can see in the example, when I scroll, the text below the menu when scrolling "jumps up", it is difficult to explain what I mean, but if you look at it, you will immediately see what the problem is. Could anyone help me with fixing this?

Comment: Here is the example: http://meteotemplate.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add .sectionHeading a dynamic margin:top equal to the height of the menu, with the same event that triggers the fixed class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this on a trial and error basis. And you need to change a static parent. Check this example and follow it.

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 125)
      $("body").addClass("fixed");
    else
      $("body").removeClass("fixed");
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
h1, h2 {font-weight: normal;}
h1 {font-size: 1.5em;}
h2 {font-size: 1.25em;}
h1, h2, p {margin: 0 0 15px;}
.fixed {padding-top: 42px;}
.fixed .static {position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%; background: #fff; padding-bottom: 15px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Static Header Example</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At, cumque inventore laudantium quod, vel pariatur dolore obcaecati veniam aspernatur aliquam ad dolorum possimus illo facilis et totam nam unde, sint?</p>
<h2 class="static">This is gonna be Static!</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis tempore praesentium eos odio nobis dignissimos labore expedita corrupti sapiente perferendis consequuntur, in, eveniet error! Officiis iste architecto eos? Deserunt, delectus!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, blanditiis dolore ipsum odit sint delectus assumenda excepturi dolor rem aperiam magni eligendi quidem suscipit nam ullam porro tenetur tempora ut!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis tempore praesentium eos odio nobis dignissimos labore expedita corrupti sapiente perferendis consequuntur, in, eveniet error! Officiis iste architecto eos? Deserunt, delectus!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, blanditiis dolore ipsum odit sint delectus assumenda excepturi dolor rem aperiam magni eligendi quidem suscipit nam ullam porro tenetur tempora ut!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're changing the class of the your menu from `default` to `fixed` the height of your document will reduce by the height of your menu because you have changed the `display` of your menu.

The solution is that when you change the class of the menu from `default` to `fixed` you can add some `padding` to your document's `body` (the height of the menu element is fine) and remove the `padding` when changing the class of the menu from `fixed` to `default`.

```
$(function(){
    var menu = $('#menu'),
    pos = menu.offset();
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > pos.top && menu.hasClass('default')){
            menu.hide(1, function(){
                $(this).removeClass('default').addClass('fixed').show(1);
                $('body').css('padding-top', '111px');
            });
        } else if($(this).scrollTop() <= pos.top && menu.hasClass('fixed')){
            menu.hide(1, function(){
                $(this).removeClass('fixed').addClass('default').show(1);
                $('body').css('padding-top', '0');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another div like your menu but with `class="fixed"` and `display: none`, when the scroll reaches the top of the page, you can show that div and change the visibility of the `#menu` from `visible` to `hidden`.